# Add columns with N pictures to report

Tags: reporting-services

I am currently trying to generate a raw data report through reporting services 2016 (report builder for now). Part of this report should be a number of N columns, containing pictures that were uploaded to a local server through an ASP.NET app.

Each image can currently be viewed in the browser through visiting a URL that looks similar to this:

http://123.123.123.123:8080/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/image_name.jpg

The path to each picture is stored in an MS SQL server database in the following format:

```
    +----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
    | image_ID | filename       | filepath                                   | record_ID |
    +----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
    |    12    | image_name.jpg | ~/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/ |     1     |
    +----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Above table can then be joined to this table through an SQL query:

```
   +-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+
   | record_ID | Name  | Family name | item_serial |
   +-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+
   |     1     | James |     Gun     | A123DV      |
   +-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

The last table in turn can then be joined to the whole line of the raw data report through item_serial etc.

I managed to create my text report through a huge query that joins all the tables and returns the data for each item_serial per line.

**My current problem is now how can I:**

- Create a query/calculated field that will give me the pictures in a column for each picture (Categoryname_image1 to imageN) for each data row, linked to the item_serial record.
- Download this to an Excel sheet that will keep the same formatting (I guess getting the initial report should be the main problem and the pictures would then just be exported to Excel as well automatically?)

As an option if it is not possible to export the images:

- Download them later in Excel (update links / pull remote content or something like this?)
- At least make the links clickable so that the pictures can be viewed in the browser as mentioned above.

Many thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Have you tried writing an expression for the image path yet? It should keep all your formatting when you export to Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do not know how to do this. Complete beginner here. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the `Value` property for your image and we'll provide an expression for the path. It would look something like this:

```
="http://123.123.123.123:8080" + Replace(Fields!filepath.Value, "~", "") + Fields!filename.Value
```

This is just concatenating the pieces of the image path. In order for this to work, you'll want to have it inside a table. Since you want these on columns, you'll need to add a column group to your table and group it by the filenames. That will make the table expand to one column per filename value.

Comment: Many thanks Steven! I will need to get back to this later, lack of time now. I will mark it as the answer once tested.